# Don't steal from Riley, or there will be suffering

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, affix-riddle

> Steal my prefix and the end is here.
>
> Steal my suffix and the end is near.
>
> Steal my infix and there will be fear.
>
> Steal my whole and lose your dear.

Comment: Wow, +1 for this very nice wording!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the answer to this might be:

> **FRIEND**

*Steal my prefix and the end is here.*

> If we 'steal' (remove) the prefix (FRI), we literally see the word **END** here.

*Steal my suffix and the end is near.*

> If we similarly 'steal' the suffix (END), we have **FRI** - a shortening of Friday, which usually indicates that *the end* of the week (i.e. the weekend) *is near*.

*Steal my infix and there will be fear.*

> If we 'steal' the infix (R), we are left with **FIEND** - an evil spirit or demon, which could certainly bring much fear.

*Steal my whole and lose your dear.*

> 'Steal' the whole word and we will *lose* a *dear* **FRIEND**. (Let's make sure this doesn't happen then...!)